# Problems connecting to Database using ODBC and VB Project

Tags: vb.net, odbc, azure-sql-database

I have used the provided links to change the connection (which works)but now I have this message for every record pulled from my database

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj7mL.png)

No reason for ODBC, just it was the first result, code is below.
I am running VS Studio 2017 Pro with SQL Server ODBC Driver 17 x64. On running the application I run into this problem, is there a step I'm missing

OS: Windows 10 Pro x64 (Build 2004)

```
    System.InvalidOperationException
      HResult=0x80131509
      Message=The 'Odbc Driver 17 For SQL Serverserver=tcp:<servername>.database.windows.net, 1433' provider is not registered on the local machine.
      Source=System.Data
      StackTrace:
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
       at MMYOB.CoA.CoA_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\MMYOB\MMYOB\CoA.vb:line 11
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

```
        'Create a connection object
        Dim ConnectionString As String = "provider=Odbc Driver 17 For SQL Server" + "server=tcp:<servername>.database.windows.net, 1433;Database=mmyob;Uid=sqldba;Pwd={your_password_here};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30"
        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM COA"
        Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)

        ' open the connection 
        conn.Open()

        ' Create an OleDbDataAdapter object
        Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQL, conn)

        ' Create Data Set object
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet("COA")
        ' Call DataAdapter's Fill method to fill data from the
        ' DataAdapter to the DataSet 
        adapter.Fill(ds)

        ' Bind dataset to a DataGrid control
        dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager
```

Comment: Firstly, why are you using ODBC? There may be a valid reason but, generally speaking, you should use the `SqlClient` provider as a first choice for SQL Server and only use OLE DB or ODBC if you have a specific reason.

Comment: The stack trace seems to suggest that you're using OLE DB rather than ODBC, although the error message does mention ODBC. I'm not specifically aware that it does but that error message suggests that the OLE DB provider you're using is a wrapper for an ODBC driver. Maybe you should do what you should have done in the first place and show us your code, including the connection string you're using. Of course, this whole issue goes away if you use `SqlClient`.

Comment: Then it would appear that you don't have a good reason to use OLE DB or ODBC so I would suggest that you don't. Use `SqlClient` and then there can't be an issue with a missing provider or driver. The code structure won't change at all. Just swap equivalent types, e.g. `SqlClient.SqlConnection` instead of `OleDb.OleDbConnection` or `Odbc.OdbcConnection`. The connection string will likely need to change and there may be small changes required to SQL code.

Comment: As I suggested, your code is not using ODBC at all. It is using OLE DB. It should not be using either for SQL Server. Change the ADO.NET provider and see [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/) for the appropriate connection string.

Comment: If you were going to use OLE DB then you would use an appropriate provider, as specified at [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/).

Comment: OT, don't create a `DataSet` if you only need one table. Just create a `DataTable`, fill it and bind it to your grid via a `BindingSource` that you added in the designer.

Comment: For connection strings for Azure SQL specifically, visit [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/azure-sql-database/).

Comment: If you want to use odbc driver to connect SQL, you can `OdbcConnection` to implement it : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't specify what kind of application this is I am assuming WinForms. The data access part of the code is the same it is only the binding to the grid that may vary.

The pattern for Azure SQL Server connection string would look something like this.

```
Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=myDataBase;User ID=mylogin@myserver;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;
```

See https://www.connectionstrings.com/azure-sql-database/ Your connection string looks a bit different.

Connections and commands need to be disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this for us. You can pass the `CommandText` and the `Connection` directly to the constructor of the `Command`.

```
Private Sub FillDataGridView()
    Dim ConnectionString As String = "server=tcp:<servername>.database.windows.net, 1433;Database=mmyob;Uid=sqldba;Pwd={your_password_here};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM COA", conn)
        conn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```